# Instruction pointer when the application crashes

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

My question is on instruction pointer. The definition of instruction pointer is "Instruction pointer is a register that holds the memory address of the instruction to be executed next". However when a linux application crash, I am seeing the instruction pointer is pointing to the current executing instruction(not the next instruction). Following is an example code which is written to crash(SIGSEGV).

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char *ptr=NULL;
strcpy(ptr, "abcd"); //This line should crash
}
```

A portion of the disassembly of main function is given below;

```
00000000004004ed <main>:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  4004ed:       55                      push   %rbp
  4004ee:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
char *ptr=NULL;
  4004f1:       48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
  4004f8:       00
strcpy(ptr, "abcd");
  4004f9:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  4004fd:       c7 00 61 62 63 64       movl   $0x64636261,(%rax)
  400503:       c6 40 04 00             movb   $0x0,0x4(%rax)
}
  400507:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400508:       c3                      retq
  400509:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

In gdb , from the core dumped file I have printed the $rip(instruction pointer)

```
(gdb) print $rip
$1 = (void (*)()) 0x4004fd <main+16>
```

My understanding is that the assembly instruction `movl   $0x64636261,(%rax)` at address `0x4004fd` is crashing as this code tries to write to the `NULL` address pointed by `$rax` . My question is if instruction pointer points to the next instruction to be executed, how the $rip in gdb was printed `0x4004fd` does that had to be printed `400503` ?

Comment: Intel defines `traps` and `faults`. That your are seeing is a fault (a page fault). In a fault the address reported to the exception handler is the address of the *faulting* instruction. This is so the handler can try to fix the environment (e.g. load the page) and retry the instruction.

Comment: In a sense, the crashing instruction is the one to be executed next: the CPU was unable to execute it and thus caused a trap.  If you were to fix the problem, the program would have to try again executing this instruction.